# How to change the name Procfile - gem foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use on heroku unicorn , Procfile is already used by Heroku for unicorn server. I would like on development use gem foreman , is it possible to configure gem use different file than Procfile??

Answer (score 1):

```
foreman start --procfile myfile
```

or

```
foreman start -f myfile
```

That being said, the whole idea of foreman and Procfiles is to use the same one everywhere so you can keep your development environment as close as possible to your production environment.

I would recommend looking at the docs [here](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/) and making sure you really need a whole separate file for development.